# Is it reasonable to display "percentage data" in a boxplot, why?

Tags: data-visualization, percentage, boxplot

I have data that are in fact percentages of C (bound to clay) combusted in a certain temperature interval.

Exemplary data:

```
    C300-600 C300-450 C300-900
1       0.96     0.72     0.99
2       0.96     0.70     1.00
3       0.95     0.67     0.99
4       0.95     0.66     0.99
5       0.95     0.67     1.00
```

Is it meaningful (given the ecological hypothesis is reasonable) to represent the  percentage values in boxplots? I.e., showing the median, quartiles etc. of percentage values?

Comment: It depends how you generated these percentages. But in general it is possible yes. Boxplot is just a way to show the distribution of your data in a non-parametric way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why not, but other plots may be better, depending on how much data you have and what you want to show.

With N < 50 or so per group, you can use a strip plot and show all your data (with a box overlaid, if you like).

There are also variations on the box plot that display more information.